# expected value from some points in continuous homogeneous spatial Poisson point process

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, poisson-process, homogeneous-spaces, continuous-geometry

Let $n$ point are distributed as per a homogeneous spatial Poisson process of rate $λ$ in a square of side $2a$, and assume that $4$ fixed points are located at $(a/2,a/2)$, $(-a/2,a/2)$, $(a/2,-a/2)$ and $(-a/2,-a/2)$, when the center of the square is $(0,0)$. 
If the sum of the distance between each random point and 4 fixed points be a random variable called X. How can I find the expected value $E(X)$?

Comment: What makes you think this has an answer? Closed forms of mean Euclidean distances (as opposed to mean squared Euclidean distances) are notoriously difficult/impossible to compute.

Comment: The expected value of the distance between the random points and the center of the square is computed in [link](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1200556).